# Android: Costum laucher to display application in a portion of the screen

Tags: android

I want to create a custom launcher so that, I'll have list of app icons on the right side of the screen, and when the user clicks on an app icon, it'll open the application on the left side of the home screen (this is the part that I still miss).
Is that doable? if so, where should I start? any links or resources of suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is that doable?" -- only via very substantial modifications to the Android OS and framework classes. I would estimate this at at least 100 developer-years, so I hope that you have a large and talented development team.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this huge team. I thought it's something more simple, I wanted just to customize the UI part of the OS.